# C# webbrowser control - input click

Tags: c#, .net

I have this form

```
<form method='POST' action='1.php'>
    <input type='hidden' name='min' value='24'>
    <input type='hidden' name='max' value='27'>
    <input type='hidden' name='do_some' value='1'>

    <input type='image' name='do_some' class='image cmd' src='images/1.png' alt='1'
                        onMouseOver="doImage()"/ >
    <input type='image' name='do_search' class='image cmd' src='images/2.png' alt='2'
                        onMouseOver="doImage()"/ ></form>
```

but I need to click on "input name='do_search'" and when I do

```
webBr.Document.All.GetElementsByName("do_search").Cast<HtmlElement>().First().InvokeMember("click");
```

it's always click "input name='do_some'".

I think all I need its male a click with X and Y... but here new problem I can not find how... ?

Answer (score 0):

You have two inputs with the same name.

```
 <input type='hidden' name='do_some' value='1'>  
 <input type='image' name='do_some' class='image 
cmd' src='images/1.png' alt='1' onMouseOver="doImage()"/ >
```

Comment: yes I know but this part I can not change! and if I click by mouse its work fine!!  How I can make it work with code... ?

Comment: Yes it NOT my website!!

Its any way I can add X and Y to click from code?

Comment: How are you editing code without being able to edit the html?